# ng-repeat inside of ng-repeat- filters not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying the ng-repeat content in two columns.

Using this code works fine:

```
        <div class=storerow ng-repeat="store in stores track by $index" ng-if="$index%2==0">
            <div ng-repeat="i in [$index,$index+1]" ng-if="stores[i]!=null" class="ngrepeatstore">
                    <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url({{stores[i].image}})" ng-click="tileClicked({{stores[i].id}})">
                    </div>
        </div>
```

However, when I add a filter- it breaks the NG repeat and no content appears:

```
        <div class=storerow ng-repeat="store in stores track by $index" ng-if="$index%2==0">
            <div ng-repeat="i in [$index,$index+1] | filter: greaterThan('order', 0) | orderBy:'order'" ng-if="stores[i]!=null" class="ngrepeatstore">
                    <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url({{stores[i].image}})" ng-click="tileClicked({{stores[i].id}})">
                    </div>
        </div>
```

the .js for greaterThan

```
    $scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
    return function(item){
      return item[prop] > val;
    }}
```

I tried adding the filter to the first ng-repeat- however that doesn't work as it just applies the filter to the overall content (ie if just one item is greatThan 0, it shows all items- not just the ones greater than 0).

Comment: Try removing the "orderBy" filter just to isolate if the cause is from the "greaterThan()" filter. Can we see your "greaterThan()" code or can you setup a sample fiddle?

Comment: My greaterThan code has been added. I've removed the "orderBy" filter and still no content appears.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're actually telling Angular to filter the property `order` on `[$index, $index + 1]`, an array of two integers, which makes no sense.

I.E. With your delegate comparing `index.prop > val`, what you're really doing is comparing `index['order'] > someValue`.

This Plunker demonstrates: http://plnkr.co/edit/FkSrmZuuK4B1ToGNgAnq?p=preview  You need to move `filter:greaterThan(prop, val)` up to the parent `ng-repeat`.  Only there will your filter work.

```
<div ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:greaterThan2('id', 0) | orderBy:'name'" ng-if="$even">
  {{store.name}}
  <div ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index+1] | orderBy:angular.identity:true" ng-if="stores[i] !== null">
    <strong>store.id</strong> {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not displaying the data in two columns as I need it to be AND the orderBy has no affect

Comment: I'm merely demonstrating the error in your filter. I don't know what your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve. You will have to figure the rest for yourself.

Comment: The data looks like this {image:"green", order:2},{image:"blue", order:3},{image:"yellow", order:1}